# Display all elements align in separeted lines

Tags: html, css

i'm studying alignments in css and html and have a doubt.

how can i put each element of this 'login form' in different lines while keeping then centered horizontaly and verticaly?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="form">
      <div class="fields">
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/leaf-blue.png">
        <input type="text" placeholder="usuario">
        <input type="password" placeholder="senha">
        <button class="btn-log">some action</button>
        <a>some text</a>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

img{
  width: 30%;
}

.tr{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form{
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: You have `display: flex` on `.form` instead of `.fields`. You're also missing `flex-direction: column`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the effect you want?

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

img {
  width: 30%;
}

.tr {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  text-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="form">
      <div class="fields">
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/leaf-blue.png">
        <input type="text" placeholder="usuario">
        <input type="password" placeholder="senha">
        <button class="btn-log">some action</button>
        <a>some text</a>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: kind off, but I don't understand why the text and image are not being centered as the rest of the fields.

Comment: thanks for the help, adding the flex-direcito: column solve the problem i mentioned earlier.

Comment: You mean the values in the input fields? Just needs `text-align: center`; I updated the snippet.